# Wordpress ajax call returns entire html page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am migrating a web app into my wordpress site.  I would like to house the app on one wordpress page.  When I initialize the content with an ajax call on page load, I receive what looks like the html string for the entire page.

## php code housed in functions.php

```
<?php 

function my_scripts_method() {

    if (is_page('testpage')) {
        wp_register_script(
            'ajaxexample',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajaxexample.js',
            array('jquery')     );
        wp_enqueue_script('ajaxexample');
        wp_localize_script( 'ajaxexample', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');




    function example_ajax_request() {


        if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

            $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];

            // Trivial action
            if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
                $fruit = 'Apple';
            }


            // return this to js function
            echo $fruit;



        }

       die();
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

## and the javascript file `ajaxexample.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
    var fruit = 'Banana';

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'nopriv_example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            alert('data:'+data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });  

});
```

When I load 'testpage,' my ajax return looks something like:

```
data:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>testpage | TITLE </title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="MYSITEURL/xmlrpc.php">
    <!-- start favicon and apple icons -->
                            <!-- end favicons and apple icons -->
...
```

My understanding is that the ajax request successfully reaches `admin-ajax.php` but I do not understand the return, as I expect the wp file to pass the content to my example_ajax_request function.  How can I get my ajax request to be handled properly by the intended php script?

Comment: is the "fruit" part in the response?

Comment: It is not.  The return string appears to be cut off at around 10,000 characters.  the final content looks like `jQuery.fn.tpessential.defaults.ajaxTypes.push({type:"revslider",func:ajaxRevslider,killfunc:ajaxRemoveRevslider,openAnimationSpeed:0.3});   

       // type:  Name of the Post to load via Ajax into the Essential Grid Ajax Container

       // func: the Function Name which is Called once the Item with the Post Type has been clicked

       // killfunc: function to kill in case the Ajax Wi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  `no_priv` from your ajax function

```
 $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            alert('data:'+data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I thought it would not work without the no_priv prefix for users who are not logged in, but I was wrong.  The ajax return remains the same when I make this change.  Thanks.

Comment: I checked the url.  Sure enough it leads to myroot/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: id say enter the url directly into the url field to see if it works, the output you are describing is a page being output by php which is the wrong url being used. I see you are adding the url using localize script?

Comment: Wow.  Okay.  Hardcoding it worked.  Now to investigate why... Thanks!

Comment: no prob, its prob localize script is called too late, im not too familiar with how it changes the variables in the file.

Answer (score 11):

Shouldn't your url be the following:

**ajax_object.ajax_url**

rather than:

**ajax_object.ajaxurl**

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer for anyone who stumbles upon this, as the issue above is `'ajax_url'` from his localize script... where in the jQuery it's written `ajaxurl`